# How to add space underneath Breadcrumb

Tags: visual-studio-code

Breadcrumb text and the first line of code are very closely positioned which is distracting, It would be great if we could customize or add space underneath the breadcrumb or add some margin top most the code editor.

[image: Screen Shot 2022-11-08 at 5 00 19 PM]

I have tried every possible way to add margin on top of editor as well as margin under breadcrumb container by setting

```
".monaco-breadcrumbs",
```

```
".monaco-editor"
```

and

```
".monaco-workbench .part.editor > .content .editor-group-container > .title".
```

Results was not as expected it lead to an extra space overlaps the code as shown in the below photos

[image: Screen Shot 2022-11-08 at 6 35 11 AM]

[image: Screen Shot 2022-11-08 at 6 34 09 AM]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done by making a small change in vscode settings. Go to *Preferences* and search for *padding*. Under the **Text Editor** section you'll find **Editor > Padding Top** option. Its default value is zero. Change the value to add additional space above the first line of your file.

[image]

Comment: Note that this only works for the first line of the file - literally line 1.  Once you scroll down there is no padding top for lines 2-end of file.